# ¿Como sacar potencias a un numero hasta elevarlo al 10?

Tags: java, bucles

```
    int iNumeroPotencias = 10;
    int  valorA;
   Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   System.out.print("Ingrese un valor para calcular sus potencias: ");
   valorA = lector.nextInt();
    
     
    
    for (int i=0; i<=iNumeroPotencias; i++){
    
    System.out.println("2 elevado a " + i + " igual a " + (int)Math.pow(2,i));
```

Voy realizar un programa que solicite al usuario un valor entero positivo e imprima sus potencias, tomando como exponentes los valores del 1 hasta 10.
Utilizar la función Math.pow(base,exponente)para calcular las potencias.
Se debe resolver el ejercicio haciendo uso de un ciclo de su elección.

```
Pantalla final.

Ingrese un valor entero positivo para calcular sus potencias:2
Las potencias de: 2 son las siguientes:

2 a la 0 =1
2 a la 1 =2
2 a la 2 =4
2 a la 3 =8
2 a la 4 =16
2 a la 5 =32
2 a la 6 =64
2 a la 7 =128
2 a la 8 =256
2 a la 9 =512
2 a la 10 =1024
```

Comment: Cuál es la pregunta? Lo otro: el código que compartes no compila, así que no tenemos cómo correr y probar tu código para saber qué pasa

Comment: Si compila mi código, revisarlo bien.

Comment: Incluso para mejorar tu código y usar menos memoria, la variable 
int iNumeroPotencias = 10;
sobra ya que en el for puedes indicar hasta que número quieres llegar talque así.

for (int i=0; i<=10; i++){
    
    System.out.println("2 elevado a " + i + " igual a " + (int)Math.pow(valorA,i));

Comment: No te equivoques, @JimmyRamirez, aquí no trabajamos para tí. Te recomiendo que no hables como si estuvieses dando órdenes, y si quieres recibir respuestas correctas y evitar votos negativos, que te esfuerces por hacer algo (y enseñarnos lo que has hecho), una vez se vea un error concreto seguro que alguien te ayudará. Pero entrar, poner un enunciado de un ejercicio de clase y poner un trozo de código que ni compila servirá de mucho

Comment: Lo que pasa con el código del compañero es que la hace falta una } al final

Comment: trata de elevar 2 a la 64 y responde tomando como referencia el resultado a ¿qué debes obtener si el usuario ingresa un valor de 10 dígitos?

Comment: Tienes razón, tú código compila, sólo hay que agregarle la llave de cierre del for `}`. Ahora, para que tu código funcione como planteas, tendrás que sustituir el número `2` por `valorA`, así: `System.out.println(valorA+ " elevado a " + i + " igual a " + Math.pow(valorA,i));`. Un detalle, si haces un cast `(int)Math.pow(2,i)`, entonces no te mostrará el valor real, sin embargo,  el inconveniente de lo que te comento es que muestra para 50^10: `50 elevado a 10 igual a 9.765625E16`, porque son números muy grandes, por eso, hay quienes prefieren utilizar `modPow` de `BigInteger`.

Comment: Excelente gracias por la explicación gente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo debes reemplazar el 2 por valorA

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int iNumeroPotencias = 10;
        int  valorA;
       Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
       
       System.out.print("Ingrese un valor para calcular sus potencias: ");
       valorA = lector.nextInt();
        for (int i=0; i<=iNumeroPotencias; i++)
            System.out.println(valorA +" elevado a " + i + " igual a " + (int)Math.pow(valorA,i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hacerle los deberes a la gente no está muy bien visto. Debe de hacerlo él para aprender!

Comment: @Benito-B de hecho como el dice, solo le faltaba `reemplazar` porque ya habia hecho todo el codigo

Comment: Exacto solo me faltaba reemplazar.

Comment: Excelente  gracias por la explicación y la ayuda.  danms07,